# Initialize the property using Unity

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have the following console program. However, the property service is null and the last line in the following code block throws an exception. What I missed?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<Service.IService, Service.Service>();
        container.RegisterType<IC1, C1>();
        container.Resolve<Service.IService>();
        // var c1 = container.Resolve<IC1>();
        c1.Run();
    }

    [Depenency] C1 c1 { get; set; }
}

public class C1
{
    [Depenency] Service.IService service { get; set; }

    public void Run()
    {
        var s = service.GetSomething(); // service is null
```

Comment: Why do you have the extra call to container.Resolve<Service.IService>(); in there? You're creating an object, just to throw it out. You don't need to do this, when you resolve IC1 the container will automatically do the right thing - once your property is public, that is.

Comment: @ChrisTavares I've updated the question. Anything else I should change for better practice?

Comment: Umm, now the code won't run at all, since you're not resolving, or even declaring, the variable c1 anymore, and you aren't resolving an instance of Program either, so that dependency on c1 won't get st. So now you have two unresolved properties instead of just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties have to be `public` to be injected.

```
public class C1
{
    [Dependency] public Service.IService service { get; set; }
...
}
```

Indeed they need a public setter. This works:

```
public class C1
{
    [Dependency] public Service.IService service { protected get; set; }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [UnityContainer.Resolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660794%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) instead of creating object with `new` directly to resolve dependencies

Comment: Any benefit to use the static method instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: @NickW Creating a new instance directly defeats the whole point of using a dependency injection container. Use the resolve method to allow the container to wire dependencies up for you.

Comment: Resolve is not static method, it is the way you get instance from container. new operator doesn't reselove unity dependencies itself, it is one of the downsides of Unity